# Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps animated pins

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-maps-markers, pins

I try to animate google maps pins but `BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromView` load only static image i.e. if I load lottie , gif or apng animation it just render first frame of it. Is there anyway to animate google maps pins?

Comment: custom renderers of course

Comment: yes I use custom renderer but the result I write in description. google map render only first frame of animation

Comment: `BitmapDescriptorFactory` is android specific is it not?

Comment: yes I use this in my android map custom renderer

Comment: It would have to be done via a separate "overlay" on top of the map as Google Map pins/info are static images (this is a performance feature)

Comment: Yea I know this way and use it but I just interested is there anyway to do it.